# Replace multiple parts of a string with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I'm trying to replace all similar parts of string with anchor tags like this:
`convert('lorem ipsum google=https://google.com lorem ipsums lorem facebook=https://facebook.com ipsum lorem')`;
expected output:

```
lorem ipsum <a href="https://google.com">google</a>
lorem ipsums lorem <a href="https://facebook.com">facebook</a> ipsum lorem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function convert(string){
  console.log(string.replace(/([a-z]*)=((https?|ftp):\/\/(-\.)?([^\s/?\.#-]+\.?)+(\/[^\s]*)?)/ig, "<a href='\$2'>$1</a>"));
}
convert('lorem ipsum google=https://google.com lorem ipsums lorem facebook=https://facebook.com ipsum lorem')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function convert(str) {
  const parts = str.split(" ");
  const formattedParts = parts.map(value => {
    if (value.includes("=")) {
      const [name, url] = value.split("=");
      return `<a href="${url}">${name}</a>`
    }
    return value;
  });

  return asAnchor.join(" ");
}
```

This function should read each "word" in the string, check to see if it should be an anchor (you may want to update the `value.includes("=")` to a more advanced regex if you need), and then return a formatted anchor string as needed.

Since this is react though, I'm assuming you want to actually render these as actual links, not just return a formatted string, in which case this component may do what you need:

```
const StringWithLinks = ({ value }) => {
  const parts = value.split(" ");

  return (
    <span>
      {parts.map((part, key) => {
        if (!part.includes("=")) return <span key={idx}>{part}</span>;

        const [name, url] = part.split("=");
        return <a href={url} key={idx}>{name}</a>
      })}
    </span>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = 'lorem ipsum google=https://google.com lorem ipsums lorem facebook=https://facebook.com ipsum lorem';

convert(str);

function convert(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z]+)=([a-z:\/\.]+)/g, match => { let split = match.split('='); return `<a href="${split[1]}">${split[0]}</a>` })

}
```

The convert function will first look for all occurrences of `name=url` in the string (because of the 'g' tag).

Then it will replace every match with an anchor tag, where the href is the value after '=' and the text is the value before '='.